# Important Variable Direction in Random Forests

Tags: random-forest

In a logistic regression a positive/negative beta tells you that the direction that variable works. Is there anything in the Random Forest variable importance measures that indicates the direction of the variable?

Comment: https://github.com/dchudz/misc/wiki/Average-predictive-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

One possibility (without variable importance) would be to display partial dependence plots, which show you the connection between the variable and (one) predicted class. 
See partialPlot in randomForest package in R for more information.

You can also use the Partial prediction options in mlr [http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/partial_prediction/index.html](http://Partial%20Prediction%20with%20mlr)